# Angular: ng-click only on subset of elements inside a ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click, ng-class

I'm using Angular; I have have an ng-repeat loop where I'd like to make some elements clickable.
Something like the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in itemList">
    <span ng-class="{ 'interactive' : item.clickable }"
          ng-click="doSomething(item)"> .... </span>
</div>
```

Where doSomething in the controller is something like

```
$scope.doSomething = function(item) {
    if (!item.clickable) return;
    /* do stuff */
};
```

This works, but my fear is that if most of the elements are not clickable setting lot of useless handlers could slow down the page. Is it the case ? If it is so, is there a way to set the `ng-click` attribute only where needed, i.e. only for those elements such that `item.clickable === true` ?

Comment: A bit hacky but you should be able to do `ng-click="!item.clickable || doSomething(item)"`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TFmjQ/11/)**

**script**

```
angular.module('main', []);
// Main Controller
function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.itemList = [{
        clickable: true,
        id:1,
        name: "ABC-Name"
    }, {
        clickable: false,
        id:2,
        name: "XYZ-Name"
    }, {
        clickable: true,
        id:3,
        name: "LMN-Name"
    }];

    $scope.doSomething = function(item) {
     console.log(item);
    }
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="container" ng-app="main" ng-controller="Controller">
<div ng-repeat="item in itemList">
    <span ng-class="{ 'interactive' : item.clickable }"
          ng-click="!item.clickable||doSomething(item)">{{item.name}} 
    </span>
</div>
</div>
```